# Including a C++ header file in a c# file

Tags: c#, visual-c++, managed

I was converting a Managed c++ project to a C# one. The C++ project includes a constants C++ header file which is an external dependency present outside of the project.

In the newly created C# file, is there a way to include this C++ header file? I dont want to redefine these constants in a C# file as changes by clients will take place on the C++ header file.

Comment: It probably not possible. Though you can probably write a tool which takes this header files and generates the C# source file needed when building the C# solution.

Comment: I wrote a custom utility to do this with a pre-build action to update the c# file when the C++ file had changed for some code that needed to share constants between c# and unmanaged c++ code.  Worked great.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: The tool is called SWIG ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to include it.

You have 2 options really

- duplicate it for the managed layer, and maintain it in synch with the C++ header.
- read and parse it at runtime, and use reflection in the C# parts that require those symbols.

As noted by others, you can automate the first one.

Comment: How do you maintain it in synch with the C++ header? Manually?

Comment: I'd probably script a simple tool to read the header file and emit a C# file that contained whatever declarations were desired.

Comment: @jay_t - see David Heffernan's comment - exactly that.

Comment: I've encountered SWIG...and it seems, um, heavyweight for what's needed here... :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a huge amount of header files, you can take a look at SWIG: http://www.swig.org/

This will generate C# files from C/C++ header files.

For more info see also: http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#CSharp

The results are quite impressive! But the naming is more C++ like, than C# style... but this was expected...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, that isn't possible as the C# compiler doesn't understand what to do with .h files. Even it if did, it still illegal to have un-scoped variables declarations (constant or otherwise) in .NET.

You'll have to convert the file either by hand, or as mentioned in the comment by Joachim Pileborg, build a utility to auto-convert it to C# code for you.